# How can factory methods return instances of interfaces and abstract classes?

Tags: java, interface, factory, abstract

[ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and Service are interfaces and so only have abstract methods, which means that their methods are not implemented.  How then can we call, e.g., `future.get()`, `es.submit()`, and `es.shutdown()` methods on references of the interface type?  E.g., why can we do the following?

```
Future f = ...
f.get();
```

Here's a more concrete example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
class Factorial implements Callable<Long> {
    long n;
    public Factorial(long n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public Long call() throws Exception {
        if (n <= 0) {
            throw new Exception("for finding factorial, N should be > 0");
        }
        long fact = 1;
        for(long longVal = 1; longVal <= n; longVal++) {
            fact *= longVal;
        }
        return fact;
    }
}

class CallableTest {
    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
        long N = 20;

        Callable<Long> task = new Factorial(N);
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<Long> future = es.submit(task);

        System.out.printf("factorial of %d is %d", N, future.get());
        es.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: They are implemented by a class that `extends` the `abstract class` or `implements` the `interface`.

Comment: To elaborate on the comment by @Sotirios Delimanolis, when you call `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();`, the object returned is an implementation of `ExecutorService`, meaning it would have an implementation of the appropriate methods.

Comment: I was confused because 'Executors' class doesn't implement 'ExecutorServices' interface.  I didn't know this was possible.  Can you assume whenever method returns an interface it has implemented all required methods when using java api?

Comment: @Artur Yes, you can make that assumption.  You correctly noted that it's not possible to make instances of abstract classes that don't implement the abstract, so if something's giving you an `X`, but `X` is abstract, you're getting something that _implements_ or _extends_ `X`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question got some downvotes because in one sense it's sort of basic, but I think it's actually sort of interesting.  After all, a factory class like `Executors` in your example, can specify that it returns `Executor`s.  But, as you point out, that's just an interface, and you'd actually need an instance of something that *implements* `Executor` if you're going to be able to call those methods.  Why doesn't the factory have to tell us the actual type of thing that's being returned?

If you haven't seen this before, it might not be clear how you could do such a thing.  The important thing to remember is that if you have a class that implements an interface, then a method declared to return the interface type can return an instance of the class.  That is, you can do:

```java
interface Foo { /* ... */ }

class Bar implements Foo { /* ... */ }

class Factory {
  Foo makeFoo() { 
    return new Bar( /*... */ );
  }
}
```

`makeFoo` is declared to return a `Foo`, but `Foo` is an interface;  you can't actually have instance of it.  You can only have instance of classes that *implement* `Foo`.  `Bar` does implement `Foo`, so you can return an instance of `Bar`.

The reason that we can do this is because when it comes time to invoke a method on an object, the implementation of the method is found in the actual object that we have a reference to.  The way that methods are looked up is actually a bit complicated.  Conceptually though, you might think of it like this:  if you tell me that you're a `Foo`, then I can ask you to run any of the methods that are declared in `Foo`, but *you* get to decide exactly what you do for that method.  I only get to use your `Foo` type in determining what methods I can ask you to execute.  This is very important, and is why we can override methods in subclasses. These are called [virtual methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_methods).  One of the reasons this is so important is that it enables us to use interfaces where we can reveal a minimal amount of information about our implementation (we can choose to say "I implement `Foo`, but that's all I'm telling you about myself), but still abide by a contract (i.e., I'm guaranteed to actually implement all the methods declared in `Foo`).

The following example is a bit more in depth, and captures a bit more of the factory pattern that you see with [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html).

#### Code

```java
public class InterfacesExample {

    /**
     * An interface with one method.
     */
    interface Frobber {
        /**
         * Frob the object.
         * @param object the object
         */
        void frob( Object object );
    }

    /**
     * A factory class with one method for creating printing frobber.
     */
    public static class Frobbers {
        /**
         * Returns a Frobber whose {@link Frobber#frob(Object)} method
         * prints its argument
         * @return a printing Frobber
         */
        public static Frobber newPrintingFrobber() {
            // This returns an instance of an anonymous class
            // that implements the Frobber interface.  It has 
            // to provide an implementation of frob(Object),
            // though.
            return new Frobber() {
                @Override
                public void frob( final Object object ) {
                    System.out.println( "Frobbing "+object+"..." );
                }
            };
        }

        /**
         * Returns a Frobber whose {@link Frobber#frob(Object)} method
         * prints the prefix and its argument
         * @param prefix an object
         * @return a prefixing printing Frobber
         */
        public static Frobber newPrefixingPrintingFrobber( final Object prefix ) {
            return new PrefixingPrintingFrobber( prefix );
        }

        /**
         * A private, but not anonymous class.  Instances shouldn't be
         * made with its constructor, but rather through the factory 
         * method {@link Frobbers#newPrefixingPrintingFrobber(Object)}. 
         */
        private static class PrefixingPrintingFrobber implements Frobber {
            final Object prefix;

            public PrefixingPrintingFrobber( Object prefix ) { 
                this.prefix = prefix;
            }

            @Override
            public void frob( final Object object ) {
                System.out.println( "Frobbing "+prefix+":"+object+"..." );
            } 

        }
    }

    /**
     * Create some frobbers with the factory and test them out.
     */
    public static void main( final String[] args ) {
        final Frobber f1 = Frobbers.newPrintingFrobber();
        f1.frob( 42 );

        final Frobber f2 = Frobbers.newPrefixingPrintingFrobber( "boing" );
        f2.frob( 36 );
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Frobbing 42...
Frobbing boing:36...
```